# Trying to Publish a Workflow From SharePoint Designer 2010 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Let me start off by saying that I am not a SharePoint guru, nor an administrator for this site.  I have enough rights to build my site.  I have taken on the task of creating a site at work to make things better since it has gone through several people's hands and I take it as a challenge that I can do it.

So I have a workflow I created in SPD 2010 to send an email out based on an kickoff action in List A that references email addresses in List B since I am sending this email to people outside the organization.  I have even tried to make a simple workflow to send an email to my name in the To: field and TEST in the Subject and Body.  No Luck.

The issue lies in the fact that when I try to publish the workflow to the site, after checking for any errors (none I might add), I get back a "Workflow Error" that says "Errors were found when compiling the workflow.  The workflow files were saved but cannot be run" and if I hit the Advanced button it says "Unexpected error on server associating the workflow."

I am looking to this forum to determine if this error is related in some way to an incorrect setting in the SharePoint Server that I don't know about, if it has anything to do with a lack of permissions from the overall SharePoint Server administrator to upload workflows or something else that I know nothing about.

I have asked the SharePoint administrator and he won't be able to get back to me until next week as he is at a conference, but I would like to try the workflow out and see if it works or I need to go back and work on it more.

If the consensus is I need more rights and I will have to wait until next week, is there a way to run the workflow in SPD or can I download my site as a sandbox and just play with it there?

Any and all help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For others who have this issue, it was a rights issue.  The company did not install SPD as an admin, hence I could not create work flows.